# meaning of '' with her one gets a fresh start, this time is the one that counts''

Tags: meaning-in-context

Nature is impersonal,impartial,and indifferent. she does not give opinions, or make judgements; she can't be wheedled,bullied, or fooled;she does not get angry or disappointed;she doesn't praise or blame;she does not remember past failures or hold grudges; **with her one always gets a fresh start, this time is the one that counts.**

What does that mean "with her one always gets a fresh start, this time is the one that counts."?

What does **one**  mean here?

Comment: It means, "this time is the time that is important/significant"  We need preceding context (i.e. sentences) to know what "time" the author is talking about.

Comment: what does ''one'' mean here? it means the same?

Comment: "One" refers to "time".  As I say, "this time is the one" means "this time is the time".  It is used for emphasis, the author could have said, " with her one always gets a fresh start, this is the time that counts.

Comment: Thanks.but what about ''with her one'' ? the one here is time again?

Comment: Have you copied correctly? Have you missed a comma?  It should be, "With her ... One always gets a fresh start, i.e . "With Nature, one always gets a fresh start"  "One" is the impersonal pronoun.

Comment: I see your confusion now. There are two uses of the word "one". They refer to different things.  I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: That's the exact what I've written from the book''the short prose reader.Muller Gilber, Wiener Harveys.

Comment: Okay. See my paraphrase at the end of my answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Any way. Thank you. much obliged.

Comment: Yes, I got my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!  When you receive a satisfactory answer please indicate this by up-voting it and using the tick symbol to show you have accepted it.

Comment: There's an unwarranted comma splice in a sentence already littered with semicolons. I'd separate out as a new sentence << With her, one always gets a fresh start. And _this_ time is the one that counts. >>  The first 'one' is the pronoun for 'a person'; the second has 'time' as its antecedent.

Answer (score 1):

> with her,  one always gets a fresh start, this time is the one that
> counts.

There are two uses of the word "one". They refer to different things. The first is the impersonal 3rd person pronoun - it is used like "someone".  The second refers to "the time" and is used to avoid repetition.

**Paraphrase**

**"with Nature, a person always gets a fresh start, this time is the time that counts."**